# Automatically refresh data in react native hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-native

I'm using react native hook; my app is a list with orders from restaurant and when i assign a order to my dealer my list and my status don't change, just if I do pull to refresh

but I would like it to be done manually as soon as the data is updated

help me please
is a good practices todo refresh in useEffect?

```
const OrdersList = () => {
  const [
    {
      selectedSubsidiary: {id: subsidiaryid = ''},
    },
  ] = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [flatListRef, setRef] = useState();

  const statusInfo = [
    {
      id: pending,
      icon: 'clock',
      route: ORDER_DETAIL,
    },
    {
      id: cooking,
      icon: 'cooking',
      route: PREPARING_ORDER,
    },
    {
      id: pickUp,
      icon: 'subsidiary-delivery',
      route: ORDER_DETAIL,
    },
    {
      id: waitingForDealer,
      icon: 'pending-driver',
      route: ORDER_DETAIL,
    },
  ];

  const setLoading = loading => {
    setRefreshing(loading);
  };

  const getOrders = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const _orders = await getOrdersBySubsidiaryApi(subsidiaryid);
      setOrders(_orders);
    } catch ({message}) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
      alert(message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
  }, []);

  const scrollTo = index => {
    flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: index});
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
      <View>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          {orders.map((data, index) => {
            if (
              data.id === cancel ||
              data.id === delivered ||
              data.id === inTransit ||
              data.id === assigned
            ) {
              return null;
            }
            return (
              <StatusRow
                key={index}
                data={data}
                statusInfo={statusInfo}
                index={index}
                scrollTo={scrollTo}
                refreshing={true}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={orders}
        ref={ref => setRef(ref)}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={getOrders} />
        }
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          if (
            item.id === cancel ||
            item.id === delivered ||
            item.id === inTransit ||
            item.id === assigned
          ) {
            return null;
          }
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <StatusContainer
                name={item.name}
                statusInfo={statusInfo}
                array={item.order}
                statusIndex={index}
                refreshing={true}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
      <CustomModal />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN1aW.png)

Comment: You need to describe your problem more precisely. Like at this point I have no idea if order list is handled in one client browser window or there is some view for some order manager and separate for client...

Comment: @Xesenix sorry, add the code

Comment: now it looks like you are doing request to get data and then you stop caring for any changes. You can try using observer pattern or use some socket to listen to changes of data it depends if the person who is changing that data is the same person who is viewing it. You can look into redux/mobx for handling data management in that case. If person that changes data may be some totally different person you need to use sockets to listen on changes coming from server.

Comment: @Xesenix damn, I'll try it with redux, thanks so much, I'm new to react native and had no idea where to start with automatic refresh 

Comment: redux may be a little bit harder than mobix but it depends on your previous experiance but in general you can even use rxjs if you know how to use it. React in general alllows you to use whatever tools feel best for you.

Comment: ok ok , I will read the documentation of both and see how to apply it to the project

Comment: Can you please add the code which you call when you are assigning a new order?

Comment: asyncstorage can also help